# How can I fix NoSuchElementException error in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is the HTML of search of virustotal but I'm receiving the below error.

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control px-3 position-absolute h-100 bg-transparent" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus="" placeholder="URL, IP address, domain, or file hash">
```

**Error:**

```
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchInput")
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="searchInput"]"}
```

**My code:**

```
PATH = r"D:\VT Automation\chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')

# Set up Chrome options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")
time.sleep(5)

# Locate the search input element
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchInput")

search.send_keys("759b1fcbdf4ad54bb8adc2c060df8ab5")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for the result element to be present
try:
    result = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "positives"))
    )
    print(result.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` element is within multiple `shadow-root` elements. In such cases, selenium can't directly interact with the desired element. You can interact with desired element using `Javascript` as in the below code.

[image]

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('home-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-search-bar').shadowRoot.querySelector('input#searchInput')")))).send_keys("test")
driver.quit()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it is working. This is the updated code:
<
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
search_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('home-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-search-bar').shadowRoot.querySelector('input#searchInput')"))))
search_input.send_keys("759b1fcbdf4ad54bb8adc2c060df8ab5")
search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # Press Enter
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
>

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me to save the result at txt file.
This is the HTML of the result:

<div class="positives"> <!--?lit$32274217$-->39 </div>

Comment: Create a new question for saving the result as a txt file. This way new question will be viewed by many other contributors.

Comment: Done.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481230/how-to-fix-error-driver-find-elementby-class-name-name-and-save-the-result-a)

Comment: could you please help me regarding this question, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77676449/error-while-running-local-python-script-on-a-virtual-environment-google-colab]

Answer (score 0):

Based on page I saw. The element haven't render on moment of calling `driver.find_element`.

You should try to use wait for search element as you did with `WebDriverWait` or try implicit wait https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but unfortunately I received the same error


This is the updated code:
# Add implicit wait
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # Set the implicit wait time (in seconds)

driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")

# Locate the search input element
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchInput")