# How to fix error driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, name), and save the result at txt file?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is the HTML of the results of any search at virustotal.

```
<div class="positives"> <!--?lit$32274217$-->39 </div>
```

[HTML image of the website and the needed data to be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSvfl.png)

**My Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
search_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('home-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-search-bar').shadowRoot.querySelector('input#searchInput')"))))
search_input.send_keys("759b1fcbdf4ad54bb8adc2c060df8ab5")
search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # Press Enter
time.sleep(5)

# Get the result and write it to a file
result = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'div > div > div.positives')
result_text = str(result.text)
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(result_text)
    f.write('\n' * 10)

driver.quit()
```

**Error:**

```
 result = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'div > div > div.positives')
 in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause of the error:**

```
result = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'div > div > div.positives')
```

Above line is incorrect. It should be `By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > div > div.positives'`

**Solution:** Having said the above, just the same way as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77480741/7598774), you need to handle `shadow-root` elements.

Change the code as below:

```
result = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-main-generic-report').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-detections-widget').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.positives')"))))
# result = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'div > div > div.positives')
```

**UPDATE:**

```
result = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-main-generic-report').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-detections-widget').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.positives')"))))
# result = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'positives')
result_text = str(result.text)
print(result_text)
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(result_text)
    f.write('\n' * 10)

driver.quit()
```

Console result:

```
39

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: unfortunately, the need result which is in my example "39" is not printed.
<div class="positives"> <!--?lit$32274217$-->39 </div>

Comment: I added a picture in the question to elaborate more

Comment: I can see the `output.txt` in my working directory, and it has the value `39` in it. Just to confirm I used `print(result_text)` in the code(Check the updated code). `39` gets printed in the console.

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: could you please help me regarding this question?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77489170/how-to-solve-try-and-except-error-in-python]