# How to solve Try and Except Error in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a function to restart the VPN in order to change my IP when a Captcha error occurs, but the function is used for any error, not just Captcha errors.

**Get HTML of Virustotal Captcha**

`captcha = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('vt-ui-shell').shadowRoot.querySelector('captchaContainer')"))))` 
[Virustotal Captcha HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltnov.png)

```
def restart_program(program_path, current_position, driver):
    # Save the current position to a file
    with open('restart_position.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(current_position))

    # Wait for 1 minute
    print("Waiting for 1 minute...")
    time.sleep(60)

    # Restart the program
    try:
        print(f"Restarting {program_path}")
        subprocess.run(["taskkill", "/f", "/im", os.path.basename(program_path)], check=True)
        subprocess.Popen([program_path], shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    # Quit the browser
    driver.quit()
```

**Main**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    program_path = r"C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP\Cloudflare WARP.exe"

    while True:
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()

            # Read the restart position from the file
            try:
                with open('restart_position.txt', 'r') as f:
                    restart_position = int(f.read())
            except FileNotFoundError:
                restart_position = 0

            with open('IOCs.txt', 'r') as file:
                IOCs = [line.strip() for line in file]

            for i, IOC in enumerate(IOCs[restart_position:], start=restart_position):
                perform_Scan(IOC)
```

Comment: you can't bypass reCapture, its not simply clicking a button, the "widget" listens to your mouse movements, and cookies

Comment: so firstly emulate some random mouse movements, (just record your own mouse movements, then just reply them each time you want to click it) then click it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dean. I don't want to bypass the Re-captcha. Maybe I explained it in a wrong way. What I need is to modify the condition such that the Program only restarts when the error only related to captcha not because of any error

Comment: Debug the exception being raised and catch just that exception.